# Clicar em um Menu, e alterar o icon dos demais

Tags: android, submenu

Boa Tarde, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho um subMenu, onde o usuário irá selecionar a Layer do mapa.

Estes SubMenu's terão uma imagem de *check* para informar qual está selecionada.

Segue o xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.app.map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_layers"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_layers"
        android:title="@string/camadas"
        com.app.map:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/layer_normal"
                android:title="@string/normal"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background">

            </item>
            <item android:id="@+id/layer_satelite"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
                android:title="@string/satelite">

            </item>
            <item android:id="@+id/layer_terreno"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
                android:title="@string/terreno">

            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Minha dúvida é como remover o ícone da seleção anterior.

Um Exemplo:

Por default ele vem com o Layer Normal, ao clicar em Satélite, como consigo a  referencia do Normal para remover/trocar a sua imagem???

Desde já agradeço a colaboração!
Cordiais Saudações,

Comment: Você quer saber como alterar a imagem do checkBox ?

Comment: Não exatamente, quero mudar o ícone do menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
     Menu mMenu; // referencia do menu

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
            this.mMenu = menu;   
            return true;
        }

//GUARDA A ULTIMA SELECAO
    int lastSelected = R.id.layer_normal;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(R.id.action_layers  == item.getItemId())
            return true;


        if(lastSelected == item.getItemId())
            return false;

        // REMOVA A IMAGEM DO ANTERIOR
        final SubMenu itens = mMenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu();
        if(itens != null)
        {
            if(itens.getItem(0).getItemId() == lastSelected)
            {
                itens.getItem(0).setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
            }
            else if (itens.getItem(1).getItemId() == lastSelected)
            {
                itens.getItem(1).setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
            }
            else if(itens.getItem(2).getItemId() == lastSelected)
            {
                itens.getItem(2).setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background);
            }
        }
//GUARDA A REFERENCIA PARA A PROXIMA TROCA!
        item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background);
        lastSelected = item.getItemId();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma variável global  de menu e inicialize-o no `onCreateOptionsMenu()`e, em seguida, usá-la para trocar a imagem da seguinte forma:

Crie a variável global:

```
private Menu menu;
```

em seu `onCreateOptionsMenu()` Faça:

```
this.menu = menu;
```

E para trocar o icone do menu faça:

```
   this.menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Para obter o subMenu basta fazer o seguinte:

```
  this.menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu()
```

Comment: Se tratando de um Sub Menu, como pego a referencia dos filhos? No código acima, ele troca a imagem do action_layers o Menu que contém os valores! Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Resposta alterada para sanar a sua duvida por completo. Obrigado.